# freebsd newsyslog.conf.d set archive dir

Tags: freebsd, logrotate

On FreeBSD, I have a file named

*my_site*

in

`/usr/local/etc/newsyslog.conf.d`

The content i.e. the of file `my_site` looks like this:

```
/path/to/site/log/site.access_log 644 7 1048576 * GCZ /var/run/nginx.pid  30
```

Now I'd need to know, how I can specify the archive target directory.

I haven't found anything in the docs how to set the archive dir in a config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check at the bottom of the [NEWSYSLOG(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=newsyslog#end) in the `Files` section:

```
FILES
     /etc/newsyslog.conf              newsyslog configuration file
     /etc/newsyslog.conf.d            Each file in this directory will be
                                      included by the default newsyslog.conf.
     /usr/local/etc/newsyslog.conf.d  Each file in this directory will be
                                      included by the default newsyslog.conf.
```

For example, if you would like to rotate `/var/log/daemon.log` you could create file `/etc/newsyslog.conf.d/extra.conf` with this contents:

```
/var/log/daemon.log                        600  7     *    @T00  J
```

Then to test (don't rotate) run this:

```
# newsyslog -nv
```

The `-n` will cause `newsyslog` not to trim the logs, but to print out what it would do if this option were not specified.

The `-v` is for verbose mode.

So you may see something like this:

```
Processing /etc/newsyslog.conf
Found: <include> /etc/newsyslog.conf.d/*
Found: <include> /usr/local/etc/newsyslog.conf.d/*
Processing /etc/newsyslog.conf.d/extra.conf
var/log/all.log <7J>: --> will trim at Wed Apr 25 00:00:00 2018
/var/log/amd.log <7J>: does not exist, skipped.
/var/log/auth.log <7J>: --> will trim at Tue Jan  1 00:00:00 2019
/var/log/console.log <5J>: does not exist, skipped.
/var/log/cron <3J>: size (Kb): 1 [100] --> skipping
/var/log/daily.log <7J>: does not exist, skipped.
/var/log/debug.log <7J>: size (Kb): 1 [100] --> skipping
/var/log/init.log <3J>: does not exist, skipped.
/var/log/kerberos.log <7J>: does not exist, skipped.
/var/log/lpd-errs <7J>: size (Kb): 1 [100] --> skipping
/var/log/maillog <7J>: --> will trim at Wed Apr 25 00:00:00 2018
/var/log/messages <5J>: --> will trim at Tue Jan  1 00:00:00 2019
/var/log/monthly.log <12J>: does not exist, skipped.
/var/log/pflog <3J>: size (Kb): 60 [100] --> skipping
/var/log/ppp.log <3J>: size (Kb): 1 [100] --> skipping
/var/log/devd.log <3J>: size (Kb): 1 [100] --> skipping
/var/log/security <10J>: size (Kb): 1 [100] --> skipping
/var/log/sendmail.st <10>: does not exist, skipped.
/var/log/utx.log <3>: --> will trim at Tue May  1 05:00:00 2018
/var/log/weekly.log <5J>: does not exist, skipped.
/var/log/xferlog <7J>: size (Kb): 1 [100] --> skipping
/var/log/daemon.log <7J>: does not exist, skipped.
```

Notice the last line:

```
/var/log/daemon.log <7J>: does not exist, skipped.
```

In this case, helps to debug and found that probably the entry is missing in [syslogd](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=syslogd&sektion=8), something that could be fixed by adding this line into `/etc/syslog.conf`:

```
daemon.notice                        /var/log/daemon.log
```